# Can not connect to "xampp server localhost" with android studio

Tags: android, android-asynctask, xampp, localhost

I have tried to connect to my localhost xampp with android studio using AsyncTask class. Here is AsyncTask but it gives error saying `Failed to connect 
to /10.0.2.2:800`

I tried my real ip address cmd --> ipconfig IPV4 and some other tricks but 
they did not succeed

**belwow is my app structure**

AsyncTask using class

```
package app.buil.land.food.doymaj.doymaj;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

/**
 * Created by ProgrammingKnowledge on 1/5/2016.
 */
public class backGroundActivities extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    backGroundActivities (Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "http://10.0.2.2:800/login.php";
        if(type.equals("login")) {
            try {
                String phone_number = params[1];
//                String password = params[2];
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("phone_number","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(phone_number,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                    result += line;
                    Log.e("Line_from_php_server",result);
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

**here is my MainActivity**

```
package app.buil.land.food.doymaj.doymaj;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText phone_Number;
    EditText user_Name;
    EditText pass_Word;
    Button singButton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


     //   singButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sing_id);
     //   singButton.setOnClickListener(kyListener);
        phone_Number =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobile_id);
        user_Name =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name_id);
        pass_Word =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.p_id);




    }

//    Push_Identity db = new Push_Identity(this,"CustomerDatabas.db",null,1);


    public boolean validate(EditText[] fields){
        for(int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
            EditText currentField = fields[i];

            if(currentField.getText().toString().length() <= 0){

                switch (i){

                    case 0:

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"شماره تلفن وارد نشده  ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() ;
                        break;



                    case 1:

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"نام کاربری وارد نشده  ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() ;
                        break;


                    case 2:

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"رمز وارد نشده  ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() ;
                        break;

                }
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }



    //private View.OnClickListener kyListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void send_number(View v) {
            // do something when the button is clicked
            // Yes we will handle click here but which button clicked??? We don't know


            boolean fieldsOK = validate(new EditText[] { phone_Number, user_Name, pass_Word });



                 if (fieldsOK ==true){

                          String Phon = phone_Number.getText().toString();
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Phon,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                          // the Tooast dose not display anything
                       //    it seems that the EditText is empty buy i enter the value in
                        // in it.
                          String type ="login";

                          backGroundActivities back = new backGroundActivities(this);
                          back.execute(type,Phon);
        //
                 }
        }
   // };



}
```

**XML**

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mobile_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:background="@drawable/customized_edtitext"
            android:drawablePadding="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_smartphone"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:hint="@string/register_phone_commnet"
            android:fontFamily="@font/iransansmedium"
            android:textSize="12sp"


            />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/mobile_id"
            android:background="@drawable/customized_edtitext1"
            android:drawablePadding="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_user"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:hint="@string/register_user_commnet"
            android:fontFamily="@font/iransansmedium"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/p_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/name_id"
            android:background="@drawable/customized_edtitext2"
            android:drawablePadding="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_unlocked"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:hint="@string/register_pass_commnet"
            android:fontFamily="@font/iransansmedium"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp" />
```

**here is the url of my php page**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjGzs.jpg)

And some more information: I have Genymotion installed and also bluestack, and VirtaulBox. Do they confilct about port? I mean could these softwares cause conflicting ports Apache xampp and their ports?

Comment: Are you sure, that your apache server listens on port **800**? Usually, you would find something like **80**.

Comment: Thanks how do i find if apache server listens on port 800?

Comment: i mean how to find what port apache server listens to?

Comment: You added a screenshot from a browser. Is that one working? - Next try to access the page from a browser on the mobile device.

Comment: yes the provided link works

Answer (score 1):

My Xampp was working with Port: **80** as shown in below image. So writing below ip address as `http://10.0.2.2:80/` worked for me.

[image: Xampp]

Answer (score 0):

If you have wifi and your computer and real device (mobile) is connected to the same wifi you can use [**NGROK**](https://ngrok.com/download) software tool to run and debug your app in your real device.

Run the ngrok.exe and type **ngrok http 80**,  it will give you an address like the below image.

[image: Click]

Just use the url in your app where you use your ip address. 
It is best to use.

Comment: I am using Wifi on laptop and i run my app on Genymotion

Comment: you can also use ngrok in this situation

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes, that the browser screenshot shows a successful page load. I believe, the error page is a bit more gray.

---

There might be a firewall issue at hand. Since you are using a non-standard port, the firewall exceptions that are installed with XAMPP might not cover that.

Go to the Windows Firewall Advanced settings -> inbound rules. Now add a rule that allows for traffic on the TCP port 800. Make sure, that you uncheck the public profile so that if you are on a public wifi, nobody will be able to connect to this application.

Now check with a browser from the smartphone, if your PHP Application is accessible.

Comment: thanks how to i check with a mobile to check if i can access the php file .i mean i should i connect the real mobile to my laptop or i can connect to laptop with mobile with wifi

Comment: Just use the Wifi your laptop is connected to. Access the php file with a browser